# Arraylist<Class> passing to another activity for adding objects in that activity returning 1st activity displaying them

Tags: java, android, arraylist

My first activity in which i have ArrayList initialized and that must be passed to custom array-adapter for adding objects to that array list. here is my first activity.

```
public class OrderSummary extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Order> orderItems= new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lview);

        OrderAdapter orderArrayAdapter = new OrderAdapter(this,orderItems);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.satya);
        listView.setAdapter(orderArrayAdapter);

    }

    public ArrayList<Order> getorderItem() {
        return this.orderItems;
    }
}
```

Second activity custom adapter where I adding objects to `ArrayList<custom class>`. The elements are added on `button` click.

```
    final Button buttonName = (Button) 

    listItemView.findViewById(R.id.listitems_addcart);
        if ( currentPosition != null ) {
            buttonName.setText(currentPosition.getButtonnName());
            buttonName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              private int index;
              Context context = getContext();

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  if ( currentPosition.getCount() == 0 ) {

                     Order o = new Order(currentPosition.getmPrice(), currentPosition.getmItemName(), currentPosition.updateCount());
                      obj.getorderItem().add(o);
                      index = obj.getorderItem().indexOf(o);
                      Toast.makeText(context, "The" + currentPosition.getmItemName() + currentPosition.getCount() + "  no has been added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  } else {
                     Toast.makeText(context, " " + currentPosition.getmItemName() + obj.getorderItem().get(index).updateQuantity() + "  no has been added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  }
              }
          }
       );
       ...
    }
```

I used getter method for passing `ArrayList` to the custom adapter.
My output must be when i open the first activity it must show  the data that was added using button click i properly initialized all the intents.
My full custom adapter code used to display the content in listView.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static satya_mydream.srkrcanteen.R.layout.word_items;

//custom word adapter used to display and hanndle the row_iem

class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {
    private  OrderSummary obj = new OrderSummary();

    WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> items) {

        super(context, 0, items);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if ( listItemView == null ) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    word_items, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the {@link AndroidFlavor} object located at this position in the list
        final Word currentPosition = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_name

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_number
        final TextView itemTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.listitems_item);
        // Get the version number from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set this text on the number TextView


        if ( currentPosition != null ) {
            itemTextView.setText(currentPosition.getmItemName());
        }


        TextView dollarTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.listitems_dollor);
        // Get the version number from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set this text on the number TextView

        if ( currentPosition != null ) {
            dollarTextView.setText(currentPosition.getdollar());
        }


        final Button buttonName = (Button) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.listitems_addcart);
        if ( currentPosition != null ) {
            buttonName.setText(currentPosition.getButtonnName());
            buttonName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                             private int index;


               `enter code here`                               Context context = getContext();

                                              @Override
                                              public void onClick(View v) {
                                                  if ( currentPosition.getCount() == 0 ) {

                                                     Order o = new Order(currentPosition.getmPrice(), currentPosition.getmItemName(), currentPosition.updateCount());
                                                      obj.getorderItem().add(o);
                                                      index = obj.getorderItem().indexOf(o);
                                                      Toast.makeText(context, "The" + currentPosition.getmItemName() + currentPosition.getCount() + "  no has been added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                  } else {
                                                     Toast.makeText(context, " " + currentPosition.getmItemName() + obj.getorderItem().get(index).updateQuantity() + "  no has been added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                  }
                                              }

                                          }

            );
        }
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.list_items_price);




            if ( currentPosition != null )
                priceTextView.setText(currentPosition.getmPrice()+"");




        /*Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID list_item_icon
        ImageView iconView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_icon);
         Get the image resource ID from the current AndroidFlavor object and
         set the image to iconView
        iconView.setImageResource(currentAndroidFlavor.getImageResourceId());

         Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews and an ImageView)
         so that it can be shown in the ListView */
        return listItemView;
    }



}
```

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: the object that i added in arraylist were not displaying (i used listview+customadapter to display)

Comment: the arraylist items are not displaying

Comment: Did it display  `Toast.makeText(context, "The" + currentPosition.getmItemName() + currentPosition.getCount() + "  no has been added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` ?

Comment: ya its displaying toast message bro

Comment: You mean data not display in listView?

Comment: yes exactly bro data is not displaying...i am adding objects to the arraylist by creating object(reference) to class which contains arraylist and accesing the gettermethod

Comment: Where you want data to be display in first activity ? In ListView ?

Comment: yes bro exactly

Comment: post your full  custom adapter code

Comment: yes bro added full custom adaptor

Comment: move this line  `itemTextView.setText(currentPosition.getmItemName());` inside button click

Comment: that was another listview bro

Comment: give me your mail id

Comment: do you have slack account?

Comment: just now i created bro tell yours

Comment: email of yours bro

Comment: give me your mail. I invite you bro

Comment: check your mail bro

Comment: check your slack